# How to filter out empty list using jinja2 filters?

Tags: jinja2

Lets say I have a data in yml format :

```
 testdata:
     - name: others
       marks: 
         - subject: physics
           marks: 60

     - name: midterm
       marks: []

     - name: final
       marks:
         - subject: math
           mark: 70
         - subject: chemistry
           mark: 80
```

What I need is to

1. reject empty list `[]`
2. then get a list of  all marks e.g

desired output:

```
[ 
 { subject: physics
   marks: 60
 },
 { subject: math
   mark: 70
 },
 { subject: chemistry
   mark: 80
  }
]
```

please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) and [sum](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sum) filters

```
{{ testdata|map(attribute='marks')|sum(start=[]) }}
```

or just with `sum` (for Jinja >= 2.6)

```
{{ testdata|sum(attribute='marks', start=[]) }}
```

Comment: excellent , thanks if you add reference to `sum(start=[])` , it would be great

Comment: It's just a sum of lists of marks plus value of `start`. By default `start`=0, for sum of lists we need to set it to empty list.

Comment: Actually you can use only `sum` filter, i've updated answer

Comment: looks great. I was looking for in depth use of these filter but could not get one. Thanks again